# Codeblocks c++ class parameters appear as not declared in scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Im just trying to get some small prototype in c++ and codeblocks, but i dont know why, every method and parameter would appear as not declared in scope. This is my code so far:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Constantes.h"
#include "Game.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout <<"Incializando "<<TITULO<<" en "<<ALTO<<"x"<<ANCHO<<" a "<<FPS<<" FPS"<<"..."<< std::endl;
    Game juego;
    std::cout << "Finalizando Juego..." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h:

```
#include "../Constantes.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Game
{
    public:
        Game();
        virtual ~Game();

    protected:

    private:
        void Init();
        void Bucle();
        void Exit();

        bool gameOver;
        SDL_Window * ventana;
        SDL_Renderer * render;

};
```

Game.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    Init();
}

Game::~Game()
{
    //dtor
}

void Game::Init()
{
    gameOver = false;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    ventana = SDL_CreateWindow(TITULO,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,ANCHO,ALTO,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_CreateRenderer(ventana,0,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}

void Game::Bucle()
{
    while(!gameOver)
    {
        SDL_RenderClear();
    }
}
```

Constantes.h:

```
#define ALTO 640
#define ANCHO 480
#define FPS 60
#define TITULO "V0.01"
```

And this is my error list:

```
    ||=== Build: Debug in Gameu (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\SIMU\Desktop\ppm\Gameu\Gameu\src\Game.cpp||In constructor 'Game::Game()':|
C:\Users\SIMU\Desktop\ppm\Gameu\Gameu\src\Game.cpp|5|error: 'gameOver' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\SIMU\Desktop\ppm\Gameu\Gameu\src\Game.cpp||In member function 'void Game::Init()':|
C:\Users\SIMU\Desktop\ppm\Gameu\Gameu\src\Game.cpp|16|error: 'gameOver' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\SIMU\Desktop\ppm\Gameu\Gameu\src\Game.cpp|22|error: no 'void Game::Bucle()' member function declared in class 'Game'|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

i can see gameOver pretty much declared in the private section of class Game. I dont know what is wrong.

Comment: Is your header really called Game.H rather than Game.h? And are you working on Linux?

Comment: Sorry, is "Game.h", ill edit my mistake. Im working on Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Comment: Unable to reproduce after removing the stuff that can't possibly compile (and you aren't reporting errors about) and the SDL stuff (which I don't have). Recommend adding [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to your header files.

Answer (score 0):

You're not including `Constantes.h` in `Game.cpp`.

Well, you're trying at least. In don't know why you have `#include "../Constantes.h"` in your `Game.h` when you would only need `#include "Constantes.h"`. Are you trying to get a different file from a few folders above?

Comment: The reason of this "../Constantes.h" is because my codeblocks hierarchy looks like this. http://imgur.com/QE0NVB3. So when i include "Constantes.h" codeblocks cant found it.

Comment: You still need to write `#include "../Headers/Constantes.h"` though, right?

Comment: Nope. Because i understand codeblocks looks for headers in the "include" folder of that tree.
EDIT: Sorry wrong link. http://imgur.com/Jf8VR0H

Comment: Maybe try going up the directory twice? #include "../../Headers/Constantes.h"

Comment: Tried. "No such file or directory". Are you sure is "Constantes.h" fault?

Comment: yeah, I think I was mistaken. The issue had nothing to do with that. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt fix the problem, but i came with a solution. I dont know why it was generated, but, i deleted the Game.cpp and Game.h and created the class again(created new ones), Copy/Pasted the code and its working. ¯_(ツ)_/¯